# Error to serialize message when sending to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

i need to test a message, which contains headers, so i need to use MessageBuilder, but I can not serialize.

I tried adding the serialization settings on the producer props but it did not work.

Can someone help me?

this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
```

My test class:

```
public class TransactionMastercardAdapterTest extends AbstractTest{

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, Message<String>> template;

@ClassRule
public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1);

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
    System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes", embeddedKafka.getZookeeperConnectionString());
}

@Test
public void sendTransactionCommandTest(){

    String payload = "{\"o2oTransactionId\" : \"" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase() + "\","
            + "\"cardId\" : \"11\","
            + "\"transactionId\" : \"20110405123456\","
            + "\"amount\" : 200.59,"
            + "\"partnerId\" : \"11\"}";

    Map<String, Object> props = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer<String, Message<String>> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, Message<String>> ("notification_topic", MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
            .setHeader("status", "RECEIVED")
            .setHeader("service", "MASTERCARD")
            .build()));

    Map<String, Object> configs = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("test1", "false", embeddedKafka);

    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    ConsumerFactory<byte[], byte[]> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs);

    Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = cf.createConsumer();
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("transaction_topic"));
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(10_000);
    consumer.commitSync();

    assertThat(records.count()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the error is obvious:

```
Can't convert value of class org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
```

Where your value is `GenericMessage`, but `StringSerializer` can work only with strings.

What you need is called `JavaSerializer` which does not exist, but not so difficult to write:

```
public class JavaSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
            objectStream.writeObject(data);
            objectStream.flush();
            objectStream.close();
            return byteStream.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't serialize object: " + data, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

}
```

And configure it for that `value.serializer` property.

Comment: tks for answer, but dont work, 2017-04-25 11:11:12,133 ERROR -kafka-listener-1 o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder:287 - Could not convert message: ACED000573720
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -19

Comment: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@4e076253; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@4e076253; line: 1, column: 2]

Comment: I believe the problem is the 2 attributes of the GenericMessage class, it creates 2 jsons, headers = {id = 067-879b0, service = MASTER, status = RECEIVED, timestamp = 1493130032409}
And payload = "{..}".

Maybe this is not the correct way to send messages with headers = /

Comment: Well, that is absolutely different story. You talked about sending message, but now it is about reading. You deserve "-1" in terms of SO. If you want to send JSON, you should consider to write message to JSON manually in advance `producer.send()`

Comment: The error happens in the act of serializing, in the return of the serialize method. But thanks for the help.

Comment: It worked perfect Artem Bilan, it was a mistake on my part here, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void configureProducer() {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("key.serializer",
        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer",
        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");

producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
```

}

This will do the job.

Comment: ByteArraySerializer did not work for me, but JsonSerializer worked.

Answer (score 3):

In your application.properties file add

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: Add these to your application.properties file

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used and it worked for me

```
Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer.class);
```

From the [JsonSerializer documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonSerializer.html):

> Generic Serializer for sending Java objects to Kafka as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am using spring cloud and did not added the below property in the properties file

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```